# How to count folders in batch

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have a folder structure like this

- Root
- Sub Folder1

  - Item
- Sub Folder2

  - Item

I want to count how many folders i have one level down from where i am now and also know how to count it 2 levels down and so on, i couldnt find the right command to go deep in each level
for instance this script show me all folders but i want to see only one level down or 2 levels down

Here is example of what i have

```
@echo off

del count.txt

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set current=blank

FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO set current=%%G&& call:count

goto end

:count

set count=0

for %%A in (!current!\*) do set /a count+=1

echo !current!:!count!>>"count.txt"

:end
```

Comment: Providing a script or code snippet which doesn't do or attempt to do anything like you have asked is essentially the same a making an off topic script request. I would suggest to make a few more searches and tests before updating your code accordingly. You may be lucky that someone will help but doing that would certainly improve your chances of getting close to your goal.

Comment: The code i provided before was to easy understand what i want to know by a simple example of just showing the folders in a specific level

Comment: If `FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO` goes one level deep, then suppose what `FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO FOR /D %%H IN ("%%G\*") DO ECHO %%H` may do…

Comment: I didnt know how to do that, thanx for the help , ill try to play ith what you suggested with my original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've played around with it a little, try this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "LODC=0"
(   FOR /D %%G IN (*) DO (FOR /D %%H IN ("%%G\*") DO (SET/A LODC+=1
        CALL ECHO %%H:%%LODC%%)))>"count.txt"
```

Comment: Thanx man it works can you explain what am im doing wrong in this script?for /F %g in ('dir /b/s/d /a:d') do for /F %h in (%g) do echo %h , i want to show the folder in level 2 but get wrong results , when using just this for /F %g in ('dir /b/s/d /a:d') do @echo %~nxg it show all folders ,  P.S i dont know how to make the script look as script in comments